# how to functional component manual render to programming?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, web, frontend

How Can I Render Functional Component at Vue.js?
I'm Use "vue-property-decorator";

I want to make Functional Component in parameter. right this.

**let makeme = function(component1, component2, data)...**

This is my Code.

```js
const DisplayDate = VueEx.component("anchored-heading", {
  render: createElement => createElement("h1", "hello"),
  props: {}
});
```

```js
@Component
export default class LazyData extends VueEx {
  @Prop() body_data: Array<any>;
  @Prop() data_loading: boolean;
  @Prop() size_td: Array<string> | undefined;
  @Ref() main_div: HTMLDivElement | null;
  @Ref() loading_el: HTMLDivElement | null;
  tdClassWidthType(name: string) {
    const arrayfind = this.size_td.findIndex(item => item.indexOf(name) !== -1);
    if (arrayfind > -1) {
      return this.size_td[arrayfind].split("_")[
        this.size_td[arrayfind].split("_").length - 1
      ];
    }
    return name;
  }
  insieditem(tditem) {
    return tditem.render ? tditem.render(this.$createElement) : tditem;
   // tditem is DisplayDate 
  }
  mounted() {
    const user_level = mockupApi.getUserData();
  }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking about. *vue-property-decorator"'s $createElment is diffrent to "vue"'s $createElement?* - no.

Comment: I'm edit my question.